# Why 'gsettings range' is not showing all options?

Tags: gsettings

I [learned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78618/224025) that the `gsettings range` shows all possible options for a the setting but when I do

```
gsettings range org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme
```

It does not show me options for schemes presented by GUI settings like

```
'Classic'
'Cobalt'
'Kate'
'Oblivion'
'Solarized Dark'
'Solarized Light'
'Tango'
```

Rather it shows me this

```
type s
```

Why? And how to see these options in terminal?

Comment: I suspect that `range` is only valid for enumerated (`enum`) types; in this case it's telling you that `scheme` takes a freeform string (`type s`) i.e. the schema itself doesn't contain a list of possible values. I don't know how the GUI preferences dialog gets them from.

Answer (score 0):

The `type s` indicates that the parameter is a string. So, you can't use `gsettings range`

But a I found the available themes in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/`